# CiviCRM + WPML breaks resource links when in non-default language

Tags: wordpress, localisation, translation

I'm implementing CiviCRM + Wordpress + WPML for multiple languages on frontend pages. WPML provides the option of switching languages in two ways: via a URL parameter or a path parameter. For example:

- standard link: https://mysite.org/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=13
- url param: https://mysite.org/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=13&lang=es
- url path: https://mysite.org/es/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=13

I'm finding that in either of the URLs where the language is designated, it breaks all css/js resource links on the page. For example:

- https://mysite.org/?lang=es%2Fwp-content%2Fcivicrm%2Fcss%2Fcrm-public.css
- https://mysite.org/es/wp-content/civicrm/css/crm-public.css

I have no idea why the use of the parameter converts the css reference into the non-pretty links version, or why it prepends the language parameter to the beginning of the URL (which is why it breaks things).

Anyway -- I'm wondering if anyone has run into this and has suggestions for using WPML with Civi. I'm pretty stumped.

I should note -- either language-switch option does result in the Civi page being translated as expected. It just completely breaks the site design because all css/js links fail to load.

Comment: Not really an answer as such, but support for Polylang has way more coverage than WPML.

Comment: You'll need to look at this code and replicate for WPML:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/blob/1792663fbe683d99534a737d9a9f3bfb69c13a7c/includes/civicrm.compat.php#L87-L151

Comment: Actually, the above is an answer *sighs*

Answer (score 2):

Support for Polylang has more coverage than WPML. You'll need to look at [this code](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/blob/1792663fbe683d99534a737d9a9f3bfb69c13a7c/includes/civicrm.compat.php#L87-L151) and replicate for WPML using its methods to discover what's needed to modify the Rewrite Rules. Please open a PR if/when you do - it would be great to have better WPML support.